# MS-SQL Combining multiple rows, columns into a single record?

Tags: sql-server, string-aggregation

MS-SQL,..

Let's suppose I have a table called dbo.students with fields like

`SubjectID       StudentfName   StudentsName
----------      -------------  ------------
1               Mary           Abc
1               John           Defs
1               Sam            Ghix
2               Alaina         Jklxx
2               Edward         Mnoqwww`

Result I expect is this:

`SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary Abc, John Defs, Sam Ghix
2               Alaina Jklxx, Edward Mnoqwww`

I know how to combine the StudentfName and StudentsName as StudentName, though I want to combine all the names in a single row using the unique value from the SubjectID?

Comment: Aaron Bertrand explains all options in [SQL Server Gruped Concatenation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation). I use a SQLCLR Aggregate because it's the fastest and easiest to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string\_agg for sql server pre 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-pre-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If it is sql server VNext >= 2017 then you can use string_agg function

```
select subjectid, string_agg(studentName,', ') from yourtable
    group by subjectid
```

For earlier versions you require to use stuff and custom code as below:

```
select subjectid,  stuff(( select concat( ',', studentfname, ' ', studentsname) from #yourstudent y where y.subjectid = u.subjectid for xml path('')),1,1, '') 
    from #yourstudent u
    group by subjectid
```

Your table input data:

```
create table #yourstudent (subjectid int, studentfname varchar(10), studentsname varchar(10))

insert into #yourstudent (subjectid, studentfname, studentsname) values
 ( 1       ,'Mary','Abc')
,( 1       ,'John','Defs')
,( 1       ,'Sam','Ghix')
,( 2       ,'Alaina','Jklxx  ')
,( 2       ,'Edward','Mnoqwww')
```

Comment: `XML PATH` by itself will fail if the text contains `&`, `<` or any other characters that have to be HTML encoded when they are converted to XML

Comment: It is name, i dont think they will have special characters... If it is question poster might provided sample data...

Comment: You mean like `O'Reilly`? The use of `XML PATH` for string aggregation is is described in Aaron Bertrand's articles which explain this very problem. He also explains why he *doesn't* uses `varchar` since the table may contain non-latin text.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work,

```
select
    SubjectID,
    stuff((
        select ',' + t.[StudentfName]+ ' ' +t.[StudentsName]
        from #your_table t
        where t.SubjectID = t1.SubjectID
        order by t.SubjectID
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as StudentName
from #your_table t1
group by SubjectID;
```

Comment: Might as well explain what that does and where it came from

Comment: Thanks, this works for me based on the example,.. concat fails, unfortunately have SQL 2008 r2 to work with.

Comment: When I use the GROUP BY on ID (in my situation, different tables for my application) I get an error on a field I have selected, if I add the filed to the group by then the next field in the select fails (and so on) with the same error:

Column 'dbo.AB_AB_ABC.State' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte(SubjectID,StudentfName,StudentsName)
AS
(

SELECT 1,'Mary'  ,'Abc'     Union all
SELECT 1,'John'  ,'Defs'    Union all
SELECT 1,'Sam'   ,'Ghix'    Union all
SELECT 2,'Alaina','Jklxx'   Union all
SELECT 2,'Edward','Mnoqwww'
)
SELECT   SubjectID ,(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CONCAT(CAST( StudentfName AS VARCHAR(50)), ',' ,CAST(StudentsName AS VARCHAR(50)))
        FROM cte i  WHERE i.SubjectID =u.SubjectID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) AS Studentfullname
From cte u
group by SubjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called String aggregation or Grouped concatenation.

There are multiple techniques. All are described in Aaron Bertrand's articles, eg [Grouped Concatenation in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation).

The fastest and simplest *to use* is to create and use a SQLCLR Aggregate. Using [GROUPED_CONCAT_S](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/) as Aaron Bertrand does:

```
SELECT 
   SubjectID, 
   dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_S(StudentfName + ' ' + StudentsName, 1)
FROM dbo.Students
GROUP BY SubjectID
ORDER BY SubjectID;
```

Writing and deploying the SQLCLR aggregate requires a few steps, but the memory, performance and usability benefits are significant.

SQL Server 2017 will offer a native `STRING_AGG` that will be faster even than SQLCLR, eg:

```
SELECT 
   SubjectID, 
   STRING_AGG(StudentfName + ' ' + StudentsName, 1)
FROM dbo.Students
GROUP BY SubjectID
ORDER BY SubjectID;
```

Next comes XML PATH. It's easier to *type* but not that easy to use. Essentially, you convert all fields to XML elements and combine them with an XPATH using an empty string as an element tag:

```
SELECT SubjectID, 
       Students = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + 
                         StudentfName + ' ' + StudentsName
                         FROM Students AS p2
                         WHERE p2.SubjectID = p.SubjectID 
                         ORDER BY StudentfName, StudentsName
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')
                      ,1, 2, N'')
FROM Students AS p
GROUP BY subjectid
ORDER BY subjectid;
```

Notice the `PATH, TYPE).value(...)` function. If the fields contained any characters that have special meaning for XML like `'`, `<` or `&`, they would get XML encoded, eg to `&gt;`. `,TYPE).value()` returns the element's value instead.

The other techniques aren't really used because they are more cumbersome and far slower.