# String_agg for SQL Server before 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation, string-agg

Can anyone help me make this query work for SQL Server 2014?

This is working on Postgresql and probably on SQL Server 2017. On Oracle it is `listagg` instead of `string_agg`.

Here is the SQL:

```
select 
    string_agg(t.id,',') AS id
from 
    Table t
```

I checked on the site some xml option should be used but I could not understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In SQL Server pre-2017, you can do:

```
select stuff( (select ',' + cast(t.id as varchar(max))
               from tabel t
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            );
```

The only purpose of `stuff()` is to remove the initial comma.  The work is being done by `for xml path`.

Comment: This is not going to give expected results if the text contains characters such as `<`, `>`, etc.

Comment: To address the xml entity references issue, `select stuff( (select ',' + cast(t.id as varchar(max))
               from tabel t
               for xml path (''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''
            );`

Comment: @TT. . . . This does assume that the `id` is numeric, which is why there is an explicit `cast()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was more or less going off on the title, seeking a replacement for string_agg in the broadest sense. Personally, I go for the TYPE + value construct in all cases, just as a sort of a template.

Comment: A good explanation about For Xml Path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463960/7786739).

Comment: Is there a method to mimic the 'Within Group'  feature as well?

Comment: See the below answer which explains how to do this, @BGDev .

Comment: If making this into a UDF (to mimic `STRING_AGG`) what would the parameter type be?

Comment: User Defined functions can't be aggregates, @M.M . You would have to use CLR for that.

Answer (score 23):

Note that for some characters, the values will be escaped when using `FOR XML PATH`, for example:

```sql
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + V.String
              FROM (VALUES('7 > 5'),('Salt & pepper'),('2
lines'))V(String)
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
```

This returns the string below:

```
7 &gt; 5,Salt &amp; pepper,2&#x0D;
lines'
```

This is unlikely desired. You can get around this using `TYPE` and then getting the value of the XML:

```sql
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + V.String
              FROM (VALUES('7 > 5'),('Salt & pepper'),('2
lines'))V(String)
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'');
```

This returns the string below:

```
7 > 5,Salt & pepper,2
lines
```

This would replicate the behaviour of the following:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(V.String,',')
FROM VALUES('7 > 5'),('Salt & pepper'),('2
lines'))V(String);
```

---

Of course, there might be times where you want to group the data, which the above doesn't demonstrate. To achieve this you would need to use a correlated subquery. Take the following sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                          GroupID int,
                          SomeCharacter char(1));

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (GroupID, SomeCharacter)
VALUES (1,'A'), (1,'B'), (1,'D'),
       (2,'C'), (2,NULL), (2,'Z');
```

From this wanted the below results:

| GroupID | Characters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B,D |
| 2 | C,Z |

To achieve this you would need to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT MT.GroupID,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + sq.SomeCharacter 
              FROM dbo.MyTable sq
              WHERE sq.GroupID = MT.GroupID --This is your correlated join and should be on the same columns as your GROUP BY
                                            --You "JOIN" on the columns that would have been in the PARTITION BY
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
GROUP BY MT.GroupID; --I use GROUP BY rather than DISTINCT as we are technically aggregating here
```

So, if you were grouping on 2 columns, then you would have 2 clauses your sub query's `WHERE`: `WHERE MT.SomeColumn = sq.SomeColumn AND MT.AnotherColumn = sq.AnotherColumn`, and your outer `GROUP BY` would be `GROUP BY MT.SomeColumn, MT.AnotherColumn`.

---

Finally, let's add an `ORDER BY` into this, which you also define in the subquery. Let's, for example, assume you wanted to sort the data by the value of the `ID` descending in the string aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MT.GroupID,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + sq.SomeCharacter 
              FROM dbo.MyTable sq
              WHERE sq.GroupID = MT.GroupID
              ORDER BY sq.ID DESC --This is identical to the ORDER BY you would have in your OVER clause
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
GROUP BY MT.GroupID;
```

For would produce the following results:

| GroupID | Characters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D,B,A |
| 2 | Z,C |

Unsurprisingly, this will never be as efficient as a `STRING_AGG`, due to having the reference the table multiple times (if you need to perform multiple aggregations, then you need multiple sub queries), but a well indexed table will greatly help the RDBMS. If performance really is a problem, because you're doing multiple string aggregations in a single query, then I would either suggest you need to reconsider if you need the aggregation, or it's about time you conisidered upgrading.