# SQL Server : return multiple values from table lookup from itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I want to lookup all `[Site]` values for each row's following `[Year]`, looking up the unique `[ID]`. However, some rows have multiple `[Site]` values for the next `[Year]`. I want to produce the following `[Destination]` column:

```
[ID]    [Year]    [Site]    [Destination]
------------------------------------------
A       2012      London    London, LA
A       2013      London    
A       2013      LA        
B       2012      Paris     Berlin, Madrid
B       2012      Paris     Berlin, Madrid
B       2013      Berlin    
B       2013      Madrid
```

I have accomplished this in Powerpivot DAX with:

```
Destination = 
CONCATENATEX(
    FILTER(Table,
           [Year] = EARLIER([Year]) + 1 &&
           [ID] = EARLIER([ID])
    Table[Site], ", ")
```

But I have no idea how best to do this in SQL. Any ideas greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Thanks, edited. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: FYI Management studio is only a client interface - its not the database which is just SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the table is named `Travel`, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Year,
    Site,
    STRING_AGG(Destination, ', ') AS Destination
INTO #Destination
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        t1.ID,
        t1.Year,
        t1.Site,
        t2.Site AS Destination
    FROM Travel t1
        INNER JOIN Travel t2 ON t2.Year = t1.Year + 1 AND t2.ID = t1.ID
) AS Dst
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Year,
    Site

SELECT
    t.*,
    d.Destination
FROM Travel t
    LEFT JOIN #Destination d ON t.ID = d.ID AND t.Site = d.Site AND t.Year = d.Year
```

**Explanation**:

For every `ID`, `Year` and `Site` take all sites (`Destinatins`) in the next year, without repeating data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Year,
    t1.Site,
    t2.Site AS Destination
FROM Travel t1
    INNER JOIN Travel t2 ON t2.Year = t1.Year + 1 AND t2.ID = t1.ID
```

Store that data into temporary table `#Destination` which contains `ID`, `Year`, `Site` and all destinations in a single string, separated by `,`.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Year,
    Site,
    STRING_AGG(Destination, ', ') AS Destination
INTO #Destination
FROM
(
    -- previous code
) AS Dst
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Year,
    Site
```

Finally, take destination for each site.

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    d.Destination
FROM Travel t
    LEFT JOIN #Destination d ON t.ID = d.ID AND t.Site = d.Site AND t.Year = d.Year
```

***Edit*: In case of *SQL Server 2016* or older.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID,
    Year,
    Site,
    SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + Site FROM Travel WHERE Year = t.Year + 1 AND ID = t.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 1000) AS Destination
INTO #Destination
     FROM Travel t

SELECT
    t.*,
    d.Destination
FROM Travel t
    LEFT JOIN #Destination d ON t.ID = d.ID AND t.Site = d.Site AND t.Year = d.Year
```

**Explanation**:

This example is using `XML PATH`. `STUFF` is omitted as it can cause slowdown in performance. Temporary table `#Destination` is simpler to create. Main change is:

```
SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + Site FROM Travel WHERE Year = t.Year + 1 AND ID = t.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 1000) AS Destination
```

**1.**

```
SELECT ', ' + Site FROM Travel WHERE Year = t.Year + 1 AND ID = t.ID
```

This line of code takes all `Site`s for given `ID` and next `Year`.

**2.**

```
SELECT ', ' + Site FROM Travel WHERE Year = t.Year + 1 AND ID = t.ID FOR XML PATH('')
```

This line adds `FOR XML PATH('')`. It creates a single string containing `Site`s for given `ID` and next `Year`. In front of every `Site` are `,` and empty space.

**3.**

```
SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + Site FROM Travel WHERE Year = t.Year + 1 AND ID = t.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 1000) AS Destination
```

This line of code adds `SUBSTRING(` before and `, 3, 1000)` after line in previous step, and names it `Destination`. Purpose of `SUBSTRING` is to remove first `,` and empty space, because they exist in front of every `Site`. It does so by removing all characters before the third one (so first - `,`, and second - empty space) and all characters after the 1000th character. It can be any number instead of 1000 as long as it is bigger than length of `Destination` string.

Comment: Great answer thanks a lot. Unfortunately I'm using SQL Server 2016 and I'm getting the error: **'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name**. Is there an equivalent function I can use on that line? I'm trying the "stuff" function from here but I can't get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-pre-2017

Comment: Hi @GabrielH. I've added a solution in case of *SQL Server 2016 or older*. I've used example from link you've provided. My bad as I supposed it might not work because of `STRING_AGG`. I am glad you accepted the answer anyway and I hope this time it will work correctly.