# String_agg simulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hi I am having SQL Server 2014 and I am trying to work with text columns. I understand there is a new function STRING_AGG to concatenate multiple columns with a separator however STRING_AGG function work on versions SQL server 2017 and above. Please help me with equivalent query to achieve this. Attached is my data look like. I am expecting result like

CASE_TABLE:

```
CASES
--------    
CS03972981  
CS03245184  
CS04054200  
CS02808145  
CS01618494  
CS03873177
```

COMMENTS_TABLE:

```
CASES        COMMENTS   
----------   ---------  
CS03972981  ABC
CS03972981  ABC1
CS03972981  ABC2
CS03972981  ABC3
CS03245184  DEF
CS03245184  DEF1
CS03245184  DEF2
CS04054200  GHI
CS02808145  JKL
CS01618494  MNO
CS01618494  MNO1
CS01618494  MNO2
CS01618494  MNO3
CS01618494  MNO4
CS03873177  PQR
```

RESULT_TABLE:

```
CS03972981  ABC,ABC1,ABC2,ABC3
CS03245184  DEF,DEF1,DEF2
CS04054200  GHI
CS02808145  JKL
CS01618494  MNO,MNO1,MNO2,MNO3,MNO4
CS03873177  PQR
```

Appreciate,
Krishna.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string\_agg for sql server pre 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-pre-2017)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the XML method:

```
select c.*,
       stuff( (select ',' + co.comments
               from comments co
               where co.cases = c.cases
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as all_comments
from cases c;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I try the same but query keep running for an hour and cancelling. I understand the comments table is huge. I try by picking couple of cases and it is working like charm.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna . . . You need an index on `comments(cases)` or `comments(cases, comments)`.