# How to combine multiple results from a loop into one temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this statement:

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
declare @tablename as varchar(255) = 'test'

select @sql = @sql + 'select [' + c.name + '],count(*) as ''' + c.name 
+  ''' from [' + t.name + ']' 
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = @tablename

EXEC (@sql)
```

But it gives the output comes out in different results windows and when I try to combine it with a union all the text doesn't fit it. I want to try and get the results into a temp table for SQL server is there anyway i can do this?

I'm trying to get:

```
Column Name   Count     Distinct Count
    a              100    1
    b              100    5
    c              100    73
    d              100    9
```

The statement above isn't for distinct count but i'm hoping I could replicate the same logic.

Comment: What is th above even trying to achieve? Why a `COUNT` grouped on every column? That makes no sense.

Comment: Hi Larnu, for this code what i'm trying to see is a column with the corresponding row count

Comment: How can a column have a row count? Tables have rows counts, and each column in the table will have the same number of rows; you can't have varying numbers of rows for different columns in a table.

Comment: Well i would want to see the row counts beside the column names and then the distinct counts of non nulls, etc.

Comment: Hi Larnu if you feel this approach is inefficient what would you recommend as a better approach?

Comment: @Larnu Either this is homework, or @T17 is trying to do a data quality check on their columns.  Example...  For each column, what percentage of it's values are non null?  I think adding a `SUM(ISNULL(MyColumn))` could get this done, and wouldn't be a horrendously slow `DISTINCT COUNT`.   OP, is just thinking about unioning temp tables instead of doing it in one go... One group by

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the query you want to construct really looks like:

```
select 'a' as column_name, count(column_name), count(distinct column_name)
from t
union all
select 'a' as column_name, count(column_name), count(distinct column_name)
from t
union all
. . .
```

To construct this in SQL Server, you can use logic like this:

```
declare @q nvarchar(max);
set @q = '
    select ''[column_name]'' as column_name, count([column_name]) as cnt, count(distinct [column_name]) as distinct_count
    from [table_name]
';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = string_agg(replace(replace(@q,
                                         '[column_name]',
                                         quotename(column_name)
                                        ),
                                 '[table_name]',
                                 quotename(table_name)
                                ), ' union all '
                        )
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = @name;  -- should probably check the schema too!

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff this looks really promising thank you very much, i just tried running this script but I got an error saying 'string_agg is not a recognised built_in function'. Is there a workaround I could do to fix this?

Comment: You'll need to use the old `FOR XML PATH` method, @T17 , if you're using an older version of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, apologies i'm quite new to Sql, what is the FOR XML PATH method?

Comment: [string_agg for sql server pre 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49361088/2029983)