# Sum the result under Group By Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, sum

I have table like below in SQL Server.

| Process_ID | Process_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 011 | P1 |
| 012 | P1 |
| 013 | P2 |
| 014 | P2 |
| 015 | P3 |
| 016 | P3 |

I want to get the count of Process ID for the process type P2 and P3 together. I have used query like below:

```
select count(Process_ID) as Process_Count, Process_Type
from Process_Table
where Process_type in ('P2','P3')
group by Process_Type;
```

The result shows:

| Process_Count | Process_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | P2 |
| 2 | P3 |

But I need like:

| Process_Count | Process_Type |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | P2_and_P3 |

Can someone help me how I can sum the result which was used under SQL `in` condition and `group by` clause and display it in the output?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string_agg for sql server pre 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-pre-2017)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want that one-record result set, then drop the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Process_ID) AS Process_Count, 'P2_and_P3' AS Process_Type
FROM yourTable
WHERE Process_Type IN ('P2', 'P3');
```

If instead you perhaps want to view all process type groups, but with `P2` and `P3` bucketed together, then aggregate using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Process_Type IN ('P2', 'P3')
         THEN 'P2_and_P3' ELSE Process_Type END AS Process_Type,
    COUNT(Process_ID) AS Process_Count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN Process_Type IN ('P2', 'P3') THEN 'P2_and_P3' ELSE Process_Type END;
```