# Change column name generated by FOR XML PATH in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, for-xml-path

I am using the `FOR XML PATH` function in order to concatenate multiple columns into a single row. However, I can't figure out how to alias the column name of the resulting table.

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT Comment
FROM Comments
WHERE ID = 1006
FOR XML PATH('')
```

I have tried the following two methods which generate an error message:

```
SELECT Comment
FROM Comments
WHERE ID = 1006
FOR XML PATH('') [Comment_Agg];

SELECT * AS Comment_Agg
FROM
    (SELECT Comment
     FROM Comments
     WHERE ID = 1006
     FOR XML PATH(''));
```

FYI, I am using SSMS 18.

Comment: F*Y*I, SSMS is irrelevant and is just a client using SQL Server like any other application.

Comment: Why not use `STRING_AGG` if you want to aggregate your strings?

Comment: @Larnu STRING_AGG function is not available in SSMS 18

Comment: @user9532692 SSMS is just an IDE. SSMS 18 supports up to SQL Server 2019, which does include `STRING_AGG` (it was added in SQL Server 2017). I can assure you you can use `STRING_AGG` when using SSMS 18 when connected to an instance that supports it.

Comment: @user9532692 in SSMS (or any application that connects to SQL Server - even a command prompt using osql) `select @@version` - if it's 14.x or 15.x you can use `string_agg`

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your suggestion! Where can I check my current instance and how can I connect to an instance that supports the STRING_AGG function?

Comment: Use `@@VERSION` to get your version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string_agg for sql server pre 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-pre-2017)

Comment: @Larnu My version is 13.x so I can't use STRING_AGG function unless I connect to an instance that supports it. The problem is that I don't know how to connect to a new instance... So I thought I might as well just stick with the XML PATH to do aggregation. Now, I face an [issue with adding GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880021/using-group-by-with-xlm-path-in-sql-server-version-13-x) to it

Answer (score 0):

I googled more and found the resolution as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
SELECT Comment
FROM Comments
WHERE ID = 1006
FOR XML PATH('')
),1,999999) AS Comment_Agg
```

Comment: Why do you not want the first character? Also, note that you'll lose any characters after the first 10,000 as a result here.

Comment: If you want to remove the first character, `stuff()` would be a better choice.

Comment: @Stu it was a mistake to exclude the first character. Do you happen to know how to add group by ID on the query above? I created a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880021/using-group-by-with-xlm-path-in-sql-server-version-13-x)

Answer (score 0):

**To use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate, the column needs to be unnamed.** If you don't want a separator, you can just add `+ ''`

```sql
SELECT
 (SELECT Comment + ''   -- causes the column to be unnamed
  FROM Comments
  WHERE ID = 1006
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
 ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')  -- prevents XML escaping
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE:

```
with Comment_Agg (your_field_name) as (
  select 
      Comment 
  from
      Comments
  where
      ID = 1006
for xml path(''))
select * from Comment_Agg
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).