# Select records without duplicate with specific logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tables `A`, `B` and `C` with a lot of columns (30+). Main columns for all are `Id`, `RefNumber`

Also I have table `LinkedEntity` where I can match records from different tables (`A`, `B` or `C`)

I need to select all records from table `A` and also display linked records from `B` and `C`

**A**

| Id | RefNumber | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | A101 | ... |
| 102 | A102 | ... |

**B**

| Id | RefNumber | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | B101 | ... |
| 202 | B102 | ... |

**C**

| Id | RefNumber | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | C101 | ... |
| 302 | C102 | ... |

**LinkedEntity**

| Id | EntityId | LinkedEntityId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 202 |
| 2 | 102 | 301 |
| 3 | 102 | 201 |
| 4 | 102 | 202 |

Expected result:

| Id | RefNumber | LinkedB | LinkedBRefNumb | LinkedC | LinkedCRefNumb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | A101 | 202 | B102 | NULL | NULL |
| 102 | A102 | 201,202 | B101,B102 | 301 | C101 |

First idea to write something like

```
SELECT A.Id, A.RefNumber, L1.Id, L1.RefNumber, L2.Id, L2.RefNumber
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.Id, B.RefNumber, le.EntityId, le.LinkedEntityId FROM B JOIN LinkedEntity le ON le.EntityId = B.Id OR le.LinkedEntityId = B.Id) L1
ON A.Id = L1.EntityId OR A.Id = L1.LinkedEntityId 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT C.Id, C.RefNumber, le.EntityId, le.LinkedEntityId FROM C JOIN LinkedEntity le ON le.EntityId = C.Id OR le.LinkedEntityId = C.Id) L2
ON A.Id = L2.EntityId OR A.Id = L2.LinkedEntityId
```

But this query returns duplicates records of `A` table.
Is there any way to remove duplicates and have joined values of linkedEntities? (Maybe using `STRING_AGG`) ?

Comment: `STRING_AGG` would work, but you're going to be writing *a lot* of `STRING_AGG` expressions; 1 for **every column** in tables `B` and `C`.

Comment: I don't understand how thise joins are working, given your sample data. How does row 2's `LinkedB` become `102`, and why isn't `LinkedBRefNumb` `B101, B102`? How does `LinkedC` join up?

Comment: @Charlieface sorry, my bad... added extra cell.. fixed

Comment: Hmm - seems you have artificially divided (or assumed) ID values among the tables such that ID 201 (as an example) will only exist in one table. Are you certain that this assumption will never be violated? Let's add to this - why do you NOT use regular intersection tables?

Comment: @SMor yes, I am sure ids will be different (in live db it's more complecated... has additional flags to be sure id is what i need)... what do you mean under regular intersection?

Comment: An intersection table is used to support a M:M relationship between two tables. You chose to implement your own referential strategy rather than use proper primary and foreign keys that can be enforced by the database engine. That is a very risky approach.

Comment: @SMor then can I store in one column Id/Keys from different tables?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach using joins that I tested with some additional duplicate entries in LinkedEntity (your current design allows this, you may fix this with a composite key of EntityId and LinkedEntityId and removing the Id from this table).

You do need to group your records using [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) or [one of these other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017) for older versions of sql server. Moreover, if you are interested in ordering the grouped concatenated data, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) provide additional examples how to order data.

This uses the `IN` operator and left joins to retrieve linked entities and the distinct keyword to remove duplicates.

**Query 1**

```sql
SELECT
    AId as Id,
    ARefNumber as RefNumber,
    STRING_AGG(BId,',') as LinkedB,
    STRING_AGG(BRefNumber,',') as LinkedBRefNumb,
    STRING_AGG(CId,',') as LinkedC,
    STRING_AGG(CRefNumber,',') as LinkedCRefNumb
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        A.Id as AId,
        A.RefNumber as ARefNumber,
        B.Id as BId,
        B.RefNumber as BRefNumber,
        C.Id as CId,
        C.RefNumber as CRefNumber
    FROM 
        A
    LEFT JOIN
        LinkedEntity le ON A.Id IN (le.EntityId,le.LinkedEntityId)
    LEFT JOIN
        B ON B.Id IN  (le.EntityId,le.LinkedEntityId) 
    LEFT JOIN
        C ON C.Id IN  (le.EntityId,le.LinkedEntityId) 
) t
GROUP BY
    AId,
    ARefNumber
```

| Id | RefNumber | LinkedB | LinkedBRefNumb | LinkedC | LinkedCRefNumb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | A101 | 202 | B102 | *null* | *null* |
| 102 | A102 | 201,202 | B101,B102 | 301 | C101 |

[View working demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb72d9420f851aac3341777f5b7aeb10)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried foreign key (for what i understood, i'm not sure the table are linked by id or refnumber):

```
ALTER TABLE A
   ADD CONSTRAINT Foreign1 FOREIGN KEY (Id)
      REFERENCES B (Id)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

an so on for b to c and from Linkedentity to a, b, c. Here the ms official page https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15

Then all you have to do should be:

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B JOIN C JOIN LinkedEntity
```

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is not valid in SQL Server?? And how does this answer the question?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I edited and removed the natural. Why is not answering?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
a_id,
a_RefNumber,
GROUP_AGGR(b_id) AS b_aggr_id,
GROUP_AGGR(b_RefNumber) AS b_aggr_ref,
GROUP_AGGR(c_id) as c_aggr,
GROUP_AGGR(c_RefNumber) AS c_aggr_ref
FROM (

    SELECT
    A.id AS a_id,
    A.RefNumber AS a_RefNumber,
    B.id AS b_id,
    B.RefNumber AS b_RefNumber,
    NULL AS c_id,
    NULL AS c_RefNumber
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN LinkedEntity X ON X.EntityId=A.id
    LEFT JOIN B ON X.LinkedEntityId=B.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    A.id AS a_id,
    A.RefNumber AS a_RefNumber,
    NULL AS b_id,
    NULL AS b_RefNumber,
    C.id AS c_id,
    C.RefNumber AS c_RefNumber
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN LinkedEntity X ON X.EntityId=A.id
    LEFT JOIN C ON X.LinkedEntityId=C.id

) AS matrix
GROUP BY a_id, a_RefNumber
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: `GROUP_AGGR` is not an inbuilt function in SQL Server. You'll need to include the definition of this if you want to use it.