# Select Query for Sum and group it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, string-aggregation

[image]

I am confused to getting the merge the item column. Please help me to do this.

Comment: i need select query to get required result

Comment: which database brand?

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: I am using SQL Server and i want to make view by using above query

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: When asking your next question, add the <sql-server> tag from the beginning. Don't waste other people's time writing anwers for other dbms's.

Comment: sorry for wasting your valuable time sorry again..

Comment: As you're using 2014 you'll need to use the old `FOR XML PATH` solution, demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution in Oracle/DB2/Snowflake SQL:
*(The [LISTAGG](https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg) function is ANSI/SQL:2016 compliant, but not generally supported in every recent RDBMS version)*

```
SELECT
 LISTAGG(Item, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Qty) AS Item, 
 Supplier, 
 SUM(Qty) AS Qty, 
 SUM(St) AS St, 
 SUM(Amt) AS Amt
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY Supplier
ORDER BY Supplier
```

Solution for MS Sql Server 2014 :

```
SELECT
 STUFF((select '|'+ t2.Item
        from yourtable t2
        where t2.Supplier = t.Supplier
        order by t2.Qty
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'') AS Item,
 Supplier, 
 SUM(Qty) AS Qty,
 SUM(St) AS St, 
 SUM(Amt) AS Amt
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY Supplier
ORDER BY Supplier
```

Solution for MS Sql Server 2017+ using [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) :

```
SELECT
 STRING_AGG(Item, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Qty) AS Item,
 Supplier, 
 SUM(Qty) AS Qty,
 SUM(St) AS St, 
 SUM(Amt) AS Amt
FROM yourtable t
GROUP BY Supplier
ORDER BY Supplier
```

Comment: Also ANSI/ISO SQL compliant.

Comment: 'listagg' is not recongnized built-in funtion name. this message is populate in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @MumhammadMumtazAli See extra solution

Answer (score 1):

Solution in PostgreSQL. Please note `distinct item`.

```sql
select string_agg(distinct item, '|') items, supplier, 
       sum(qty) qty, sum(st) st, sum(amt) amt
from the_table 
group by supplier;
```

**Edit**
My answer above is not relevant anymore after `sql-server` DB was tagged.

Comment: 'String_Agg' is not recongnized built-in funtion name. this message is populate in sql Server 2014.

Comment: Yes, this is a PostgreSQL solution, not SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server does support `STRING_AGG` too, however, only in 2017+. The bang the same drum, this is why it is important to let people know the product *and* version you are using, @MumhammadMumtazAli .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for SQL SERVER < 2017

```
SELECT 
Supplier
,Items = STUFF((
        SELECT ' | ' + t2.Item
        FROM TestTable t2
        WHERE t.Supplier = t2.Supplier
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
,SUM(Qty) Qty
,SUM(ST) ST
,SUM(Amt) Amt
FROM TestTable t
GROUP BY Supplier
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really learn more about SQL and read the documentation for your concrete database type - SQL Queries varies slightly for different databases. Nevertheless in MySQL you could do:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Item SEPARATOR ' | '), SUM(Qty), SUM(ST), SUM(Amt) FROM <supplier> GROUP BY Supplier;
```

Where **<supplier>** should be replaced by the name of your table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, please explain can i do in SQL ? not mysql.

Comment: @MumhammadMumtazAli, the above is SQL, MySQL dialect SQL. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What if a supplier has supplied an item more than once?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm they are concatenated by using `GROUP_CONCAT(Item SEPARATOR ' | ')`