# SQL Server - Concatenate - Stuff doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server and I want to concatenate using stuff the 'Products' column, but I don't know why this doesn't work...

```
SELECT BrandsProvider.id, BrandsProvider.Name, 
    (SELECT (STUFF((
        SELECT ','+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), sku) 
            FROM items it2
        WHERE it2.sku = it.sku
        FOR XML PATH('')),
        COUNT('ID'), 1, ''))) AS 'Products'
FROM items it
    INNER JOIN BrandsProvider ON it.IdBrandProduct = BrandsProvider.id
```

And the result is:

```
Id     Name             Products
--------------------------------
1      BRAND EXAMPLE     PR344
1      BRAND EXAMPLE     PR345
```

And I want this:

```
Id     Name             Products
--------------------------------
1      BRAND EXAMPLE     PR344, PR345
```

Also I used `SELECT DISTINCT` in the query but the result is the same...

So, where can be the mistake?

Comment: What SQL Server version are you on?

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't concatenate *anything* here. It's just removing 1 characters from the position `COUNT(ID)`. It's `FOR XML PATH` that is concatenating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String_agg for SQL Server before 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017)

Comment: Sorry, I'm on SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.id
    ,   b.Name
    ,   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(i.sku AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM items i 
         WHERE i.IdBrandProduct = b.id
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') Products
FROM BrandsProvider b
GROUP BY b.id
    ,   b.Name
```

**SQL Server 2017 and Later Versions**

If you are working on SQL Server 2017 or later versions, you can use built-in SQL Server Function [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016) to create the comma delimited list:

```
SELECT b.id
    ,   b.Name
    ,  STRING_AGG(i.sku, ', ') AS Products
FROM BrandsProvider b
INNER JOIN items i  ON i.IdBrandProduct = b.id
GROUP BY b.id
    ,   b.Name;
```

Comment: Amazing, the first query works fine, but in the concatenated column includes an space at beginning. How can I do a Trim for this?

Comment: I have removed the space now, I have changed `.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') ` to `.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') `

Comment: Oh yeah, it was the space near the 2 at the end. I change it for '' and now works!