# Error creating MySQL Group_concat to SQL Server STUFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have this MySQL query which I'm trying to create in SQL Server.
In MySQL I just use the function `GROUP_CONCAT` and in SQL Server I want to use `STUFF`.

MySQL

```sql
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(id
                    ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR '\', \'') AS id_list
FROM
    testjob
WHERE
    testjob.id IN (SELECT 
            MAX(testjob.id) AS id
        FROM
            testjob
                INNER JOIN
            target ON testjob.id = target.TestJobId
                LEFT JOIN
            dashboard_hidden ON testjob.TestSuiteCollectionId = dashboard_hidden.TestSuiteCollectionId
                INNER JOIN
            versions ON target.id = versions.TargetId
        WHERE
            target.Project = 'GiM1_0'
                AND testjob.Finished != 'PENDING'
                AND versions.Version IN ('V01.09.00.00110')
                AND IFNULL(dashboard_hidden.Hidden, 0) != 1
        GROUP BY testjob.id)
GROUP BY testjob.TestSuiteCollectionId DESC
```

I've tried to create the same in SQL Server using `STUFF` (I'm running MSSQL 2014, so cant use `STRING_AGG`)

```sql
SELECT
        id_list = 
        COALESCE(STUFF((
            SELECT '','' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), tj.id)
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, ''), '')
FROM
    [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].testjob tj
WHERE
    tj.id IN (SELECT 
            MAX(tj.id) AS id
        FROM
            [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].testjob tj
                INNER JOIN
            [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].target tg ON tj.id = tg.TestJobId
                LEFT JOIN
            [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].dashboard_hidden dash ON tj.TestSuiteCollectionId = dash.TestSuiteCollectionId
                INNER JOIN 
            [SwMetrics].[testreportingdebug].versions v ON tg.id = v.TargetId
        WHERE
            tg.Project = 'GiM1_0'
                AND tj.Finished != 'PENDING'
                AND v.Version IN ('V01.09.00.00110')
                AND ISNULL(dash.Hidden, 0) != 1
        GROUP BY tj.id)     
GROUP BY tj.TestSuiteCollectionId
ORDER BY tj.TestSuiteCollectionId DESC
```

When I run this I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Column 'SwMetrics.testreportingdebug.testjob.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The reason I `GROUP BY testjob.TestSuiteCollectionId` is because `TestSuiteCollectionId` have multiple IDs which is the same, but the `id` is unique and I want all those as a string. In this image you can see a MySQL with `TestSuiteCollectionId` and the grouped `id`s

[image: wanted]

Table without grouping:

```sql
#TestSuiteCollectionId, id
272, 37047
272, 36939
276, 37121
276, 36930
276, 37024
277, 37118
277, 37006
420, 37093
420, 36929
420, 37019
421, 37089
421, 36999
422, 37113
422, 37008
437, 37017
438, 37013
439, 37021
```

Comment: @DaleK Okay thanks, thought I should tag all the code languages :)

Comment: @DaleK Makes sense

Comment: When string aggregating (in SQL Server), all `STUFF` does is remove the leading delimiter. It's `FOR XML PATH` that does the aggregation.

Comment: Your subquery, with `FOR XML PATH` dosen't have a `FROM`, so it's referencing the tables in the outer `FROM`, hence the error. You need to use a correlated subquery.

Comment: @Larnu as I wrote: I'm running `Microsoft SQL Server 2014`, so cant use `STRING_AGG`

Comment: All SQL Server versions in mainstream support (ie SQL Server 2017 and later) use `STRING_AGG` for this. The `FOR XML` trick was used only in older versions

Comment: See [How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server) and [String_agg for SQL Server before 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017). Note the use of correlated subqueries.

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup SQL Server 2014 went out of support a long time ago. Why are you trying to migrate anything to it? This isn't a `yes but in an ideal world`. 8 years is a very long time. You can't install SQL Server 2014 legally, not even use a Dev version without paying for it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well in the company we order a database, and I think they only support 2014, that's why we get that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos have written a mail to them if it is possible to get a 2017 database, just to check up, since its stupid to actually migrate to an outdated database. also its anoying not to be able to run newer functions lige `STRING_AGG`. So thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos okay can get a 2019 version, thanks for making be ask them