# Flatten table according to unique values of identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, flatten

I have a table that looks like

| id1 | id2 | id3 | value1 | value2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | x11 | x12 | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | x21 | x22 | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | x31 | x32 | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | x41 | x42 | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | x51 | x52 | --- |

where each combination of id1-id2-id3 identifies a unique object.

I want to flatten this table with respect to the values of id3, with appropriately renamed columns. More precisely, I would like to obtain a table of the form

| id1 | id2 | value1_id3=1 | value2_id3=1 | --- | value1_id3=2 | value2_id3=2 | --- | value1_id3=3 | value2_id3=3 | --- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x11 | x12 | --- | x21 | x22 | --- |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | x31 | x32 | --- | x41 | x42 | --- | x51 | x52 | --- |

Now each combination of id1-id2 identifies a unique object.

Is there someone that knows how something like this can be achieved in SQL?

Update: it would be convenient to have it work for an arbitrary number of value columns.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am working in microsoft sql server management studio 18 if that provides an answer to your question...

Comment: Fyi - SSMS is an IDE used to connect to your dbms - which is SQL Server.

Comment: This is not what "flattening" means.  Flattening means removing internal structures and sub-structures (i.e., "normalizing").  You are *adding* [sub]structure, so it's the opposite of flattening (ie., "*de*normalizing", or possibly pivoting).

Comment: sorry, I couldn't come up with the correct term

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL then.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you'll need to use dynamic SQL if you have an arbitrary number of values for `id3` and columns (I assumed you meant both).

This, in truth, makes for an ugly query. I also assume you are on a fully supported version of SQL Server. If not and thus you can't use `STRING_AGG` you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method (I do not cover that here, as there are plenty of dupes out there, such as my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64227488/2029983)).

I, honestly, am not going to explain what this does for the following reasons:

1. Dynamic SQL is a powerful and dangerous tool; if you don't understand the following, you should not be using it.
2. This should likely be a task for your presentation layer
3. You have your "best friend" to help you debug and help you see what the actual SQL is that is being run:

```sql
--Create sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (id1 int,
                            id2 int,
                            id3 int,
                            value1 char(3),
                            value2 char(3));

GO
--Insert sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES (1,1,1,'x11','x12'),
       (1,1,2,'x21','x22'),
       (2,1,1,'x31','x32'),
       (2,1,2,'x41','x42'),
       (2,1,3,'x51','x52');
GO
--Solution
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delim nchar(3) = ',' + @CRLF;

SET @SQL = N'SELECT YT.id1,' + @CRLF + 
           N'       YT.id2,' + @CRLF + 
           (SELECT STRING_AGG(N'       MAX(CASE id3 WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(yt.id3,'''') + N' THEN YT.' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(c.name,'_id3=',yt.id3)),@Delim) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY yt.id3,c.[name])
            --Note, due to string ordering, value2 will have a GREATER value than value10
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id3
                  FROM dbo.YourTable) yt
                 CROSS JOIN (SELECT c.[name]
                             FROM sys.schemas s
                                  JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                                  JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                             WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo' --This would be your schema
                               AND t.[name] = N'YourTable' --This would be your table
                               AND c.[name] LIKE 'value%') c) + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable YT' + @CRLF + 
           N'GROUP BY YT.id1, YT.id2;';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=18099d34235cc89103f594dc4a769c13)

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you suggested, since I am not familiar with this I will avoid Dynamic SQL, and I will stick to my hard coded version where I enter the name of each column manually :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE` statement to extract the value from the relative columns, then apply the aggregation function `STRING_AGG` to merge the rows belonging to the same combination of `id1, id2`:

```
SELECT id1,
       id2, 
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id3=1 THEN value1 END, '') AS value1_id3eq1,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id3=1 THEN value2 END, '') AS value2_id3eq1,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id3=2 THEN value1 END, '') AS value1_id3eq2,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id3=2 THEN value2 END, '') AS value2_id3eq2,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id3=3 THEN value1 END, '') AS value1_id3eq3,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN id3=3 THEN value2 END, '') AS value2_id3eq3
FROM tab
GROUP BY id1,
         id2
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=1ccd301cfd91fc7a92a092d62a195b72).

Comment: Thanks, it is what I am doing now and it works. I was hoping to have something that would work for an arbitrary number of values however, as in my actual problem I have around 30 x 7 possible columns, though I can use a lot of copy paste :-)