# How to concatenate all the rows linked with a same id into one row? consedring null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, concatenation, unique-values

I'm trying to concatenate all rows for same ID, the rows for a ID can have null or empty value:

| country | value |
| --- | --- |
| FR | NULL |
| FR | 1 |
| FR | 3 |
| MA | 5 |
| MA | NULL |
| MA | 4 |
| ES | 9 |
| ES | 10 |
| ES | NULL |

I would like to consider this case in my query to get this result:

| country | value |
| --- | --- |
| FR | NULL,1,3 |
| MA | 4,NULL,9 |
| ES | 9,10,NULL |

We can consider to replace null value to get this result

| country | value |
| --- | --- |
| FR | ,1,3 |
| MA | 4,,9 |
| ES | 9,10, |

> sql server version : Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505217) - 12.0.5223.6 (X64)

I have tried this query

```
SELECT IDENT_0, PAYS_0 = STUFF

SELECT ', ' + TEXTE_0
FROM UAI.YORIGINELOT AS T2
LEFT JOIN UAI.ATEXTRA ON T2.YOMP_0 = ATEXTRA.IDENT1_0 AND CODFIC_0 = 'TABCOUNTRY' AND LANGUE_0 = 'FRA' And ZONE_0 = 'CRYDES'
WHERE T2.IDENT_0 = T1.IDENT_0
ORDER BY IDENT_0
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
     ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
1, 1, '')
FROM UAI.YORIGINELOT AS T1
LEFT JOIN UAI.ATEXTRA ON T1.YFABEN_0 = ATEXTRA.IDENT1_0 AND LANGUE_0='FRA' AND CODFIC_0='TABCOUNTRY' AND ZONE_0 = 'CRYDES'
WHERE OBJ_0 = 'ITM'  
GROUP BY IDENT_0
```

Thank you

Comment: Are the NULL values in your data actually strings with the value 'NULL'? you cannot concatenate a NULL like you show in your expected results otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Since SQLServer 2017, we can use `STRING_AGG` to produce the expected result.

In order to replace `NULL` values by any other string - even if it just should be "NULL" - we can use `COALESCE`.

So this query will do:

```
SELECT country, 
STRING_AGG(COALESCE(value,'NULL'),',') AS value
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country;
```

Of course, this is just a sample based on one table because I don't know your table structure. Just use this concept in your query.
The result of this query will be this one:

| country | value |
| --- | --- |
| ES | 9,10,NULL |
| FR | NULL,1,3 |
| MA | 5,NULL,4 |

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TMt-5cRS)

Here the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) about `STRING_AGG`

If you still use an older version, I highly recommend to update.

If this isn't possible, there are lot of articles (for example here on SO) how to do this with other functions.
Here one of them: [Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it is possible to create function which can chieve the same thing that string_agg function does , in older version of sql management server ?

Comment: I highly recommend to do not use obsolete versions and recreate functions that already exist in better and newer versions and I refuse to deal with such stuff ;) But please see the link I added in my last sentence, that's exactly about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As you have SQL server 2014, you better use sTUFF

But you should consoder an upgrade, as the ned of life was Jul 9, 2019 so if you haven't an extended support, you will become vulnerable.l

```
SELECT country,
    val = 
    STUFF (
        (SELECT   
                ',' +value  
        FROM yourtable
  WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND y1.country = country
        FOR XML PATH('')
  
  ), 1, 1, ''
  
    )
FROM yourtable y1
GROUP by country
ORDER BY country
```

| country | val |
| --- | --- |
| ES | 9,10 |
| FR | 1,3 |
| MA | 5,4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K0u6vDdV)

If you want also the NULL values represnted

```
SELECT country,
    val = 
    STUFF (
        (SELECT   
                ',' + COALESCE(value,'')  
        FROM yourtable
  WHERE  y1.country = country
  ORDER BY COALESCE(value,0)
        FOR XML PATH('')
  
  ), 1, 1, ''
  
    )
FROM yourtable y1
GROUP by country
ORDER BY country
```

| country | val |
| --- | --- |
| ES | ,9,10 |
| FR | ,1,3 |
| MA | ,4,5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P2wZG9os)

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you tel me if it is possible to replace the null value with space and get , before the second element for the same id
for exemple : 
the id FR :   ,1,3