# SQL Server : select if multiple rows because of one column, only return one with comma seperated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `address` and another `addressline`. One address can have multiple address lines.

I want a select statement that returns one row per address, and if there are multiple address lines, I still only want one row but with all the address lines comma-separated in one column.

I have only managed to do it like this but it returns the values as XML and I just want it as string

```
SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT ', ', adrline.AddressLine
           FROM AddressLine AS adrline
           WHERE adr.Id = adrline.AddressId
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS AddressLine,
FROM 
    Address AS adr
```

Result:

```
<AddressLine>My Street 1</AddressLine>, <AddressLine>My Street 2</AddressLine>
```

Desired result:

```
My Street 1, My Street 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Side note `STUFF` isn't the function doing the work here; all `STUFF` is doing is removing the first 2 leading characters from the string. `FOR XML PATH` is doing the "aggregation".

Comment: `', ' + adrline.AddressLine` not `', ', adrline.AddressLine`.

Comment: @Larnu: that worked, thank you! If you add it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it :-)

Comment: In my opinion, it is more of a typographical error. Or, if not, a duplicate of something like [String\_agg for SQL Server before 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017)

Comment: this code will mangle all "special" xml characters if they occur in the addressline. You might wanna take a look at FOR XML TYPE

Comment: which version of sql server are you using

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

Recent version of SQL SERVER (2017 .... ) , offer a new feature to your need as you can see below, you can use the same things :

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG([AddressLine], ', ') AS output
FROM Address;
```

Comment: Based on the OP's query you'll need to join the `Address` and `AddressLine` tables. And aggregation usually benefits from having a `group by` clause.

Comment: @HABO hi I'm not able to provide a complete solution because i haven't all the context,  it's just suggestion to solve the problem