# Remove character between Pipe and semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Table with a column that stores keywords like this

> keyword|44500903-8f09-40d8-a908-5fb3e03d145e;keyword2|441fb756-ff0a-473f-ad70-2f78d679e7d9

I need remove all characters between Pipe (including this) and semicolon, including this. The result must be:

```
Keyword; keyword2
```

Any ideas? I try to use, substring, trim etc... but didn't work.

Comment: SQL Server isn't really your friend here, if I am honest, however, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: how man keys are the exactly?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Would it be possible to normalize the database so that it did not have the problem of multiple values in one column?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you are on SQL Server 2022, then you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the values into rows on the semicolon (`;`) with an ordinal position, then use `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` to get the value up to the pipe (`|`), and finally reaggregate with `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(500) = 'keyword|44500903-8f09-40d8-a908-5fb3e03d145e;keyword2|441fb756-ff0a-473f-ad70-2f78d679e7d9';

SELECT STRING_AGG(LEFT(SS.Value,CHARINDEX('|',SS.Value + '|')-1),'; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.ordinal)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourString,';',1) SS;
```

If you aren't on SQL Server 2022 you could use a different solution to split your values, such as a JSON splitter (2016+) or [`delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) (2012+). If you aren't on SQL Server 2017+ you'll also need to switch out `STRING_AGG` for the "old" [`FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49361088/2029983) solution.

Comment: JOOI, at what point does a CLR function start to look tempting? Would you normalise the database rather than do that?

Comment: Oh, normalisation is ***always*** the correct answer, @AndrewMorton .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

We are *tokenizing* input string of tokens as XML. An intermediate result in t1(c) contains XML as follows:

```
<root>
  <r>keyword</r>
  <r>44500903-8f09-40d8-a908-5fb3e03d145e</r>
  <r>keyword2</r>
  <r>441fb756-ff0a-473f-ad70-2f78d679e7d9</r>
</root>
```

We just need to retrieve XML elements values in *odd* positions by using XPath predicate `[position() mod  2 = 1]`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
(N'keyword|44500903-8f09-40d8-a908-5fb3e03d145e;keyword2|441fb756-ff0a-473f-ad70-2f78d679e7d9');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ';'
    , @pipe CHAR(1) = '|';

SELECT t.*
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() mod  2 = 1])')
        .value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), SPACE(1), @separator) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,@pipe,@separator), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| id | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | keyword;keyword2 |