# Update in loop SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am supposed to make a loop in which I will update the tag and add the registration number to it

it looks like

| LP | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Mamma mia #XX' |
| 2 | 'Joe is my best #XX friend' |
| 3 | Hi hey haloo' |
| 4 | 'one #XX two #XX three #XX' |
| 5 | 'best phone ever' |
| 6 | 'Nice im love it #XX what we do next #XX' |

it should look like this

| LP | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Mamma mia #XX[01]' |
| 2 | 'Joe is my best #XX[02] friend' |
| 3 | Hi hey haloo' |
| 4 | 'one #XX[03] two #XX[04] three #XX[05]' |
| 5 | 'best phone ever' |
| 6 | 'Nice im love it #XX[06] what we do next #XX[07]' |

Comment: Have you already made any attempt to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit ugly, but loops should be the last resort.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([LP] int,[Text] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Mamma mia #XX')
,(2,'Joe is my best #XX friend')
,(3,'Hi hey haloo')
,(4,'one #XX two #XX three #XX')
,(5,'best phone ever')
,(6,'Nice im love it #XX what we do next #XX')

;with cte as (
Select * 
      ,Seq = sum(case when RetVal like '#%' then 1 else 0 end) over ( order by RN,RetSeq)
      ,Pos = charindex(' ',RetVal+' ')
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RN = row_number() over( order by LP) 
         from @YourTable
       ) A 
 Cross Apply (
            Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
                  ,RetVal = trim(Value)
             From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(replace([Text],'#','|||#'),'json'),'|||','","')+'"]' )

             ) B
)
Select LP
      ,NewVal = string_agg(
                case when RetVal not like '#%' then RetVal
                     else stuff(RetVal+' ',Pos,0,concat('[',format(Seq,'00'),'] '))
                end
                ,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RN,Seq)
 From  cte
 Group By LP
 Order By LP
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: in sql 2014 string_agg doesnt work ?

Comment: @KrzysztofJankowicz Neighbor would OpenJSON.   Clearly not a solution for you then

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could:

- split your strings on `#` characters,
- compute the amount of times "#XX" is present, with a running sum
- replace "#XX" with "#XX[n]"
- aggregate your string parts again

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LP,
           REPLACE(
               IIF(LEFT(value, 3) = 'XX ', CONCAT('#',value), value),
               '#XX', 
               CONCAT(
                   '#XX[',
                   FORMAT(SUM(IIF(LEFT(value, 3) = 'XX ', 1, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY LP, ordinal), '00'),
                   ']'
               )
           ) AS [TextParts]
    FROM tab
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tab.[Text], '#', 1)
)
SELECT LP, 
       STRING_AGG([TextParts], '') AS [Text]
FROM cte
GROUP BY LP
```

**Output**:

| LP | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mamma mia #XX[01] |
| 2 | Joe is my best #XX[02] friend |
| 3 | Hi hey haloo |
| 4 | one #XX[03] two #XX[04] three #XX[05] |
| 5 | best phone ever |
| 6 | Nice im love it #XX[06] what we do next #XX[07] |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GQOK9T7W).

Comment: in sql 2014 string_agg doesnt work ?

Comment: You can follow up with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017), although string_agg won't be the only cool tool not to be working in that version. I'd recommend to update your SQL Server version if you have the possibility, or go with *very* ugly and expensive queries, way further than this and John's.

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @TempTable Table ([LP] int,[Text] varchar(50))  Insert Into @TempTable Values 
 (1,'Mamma mia #XX')
,(2,'Joe is my best #XX friend')
,(3,'Hi hey haloo')
,(4,'one #XX two #XX three #XX')
,(5,'best phone ever')
,(6,'Nice im love it #XX what we do next #XX')

Declare @TempTable2 Table ([LP] int,[Text] varchar(50))

DECLARE 
    @lp INT, 
    @text   VARCHAR(MAX);


select * from @TempTable

Declare cursor_temptable cursor for select LP,Text from @TempTable
open cursor_temptable 

Declare @myPrevValue int=0
Declare @myNextValue int=0


FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_temptable INTO @lp,@text
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
Begin

declare @count int
set @count=(select count(*)-1 from STRING_SPLIT(@text,'#'))
set @myNextValue=@myPrevValue+@count

insert into @TempTable2 values(@lp,(select 
STRING_AGG(a.value,'#')
From(
select replace(value,'XX','XX'+'[0' +convert(varchar,(rank() over(order by value)-1+@myPrevValue)) +'] ' ) value from STRING_SPLIT(@text,'#')
) as a))


FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_temptable INTO @lp,@text
set @myPrevValue=@myNextValue
end

close cursor_temptable
deallocate cursor_temptable


select * from @TempTable2
```