# Group By with Multiple Stuff Statements - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, string-agg, stuff

I am trying to aggregate multiple rows into a single field (for multiple columns), grouped by a common ID (See below)

This is the what I have

```
ID  CPT  SVCDate    Vendor 
1   A3A  1/14/2023   A      
2   DC6  1/23/2023   B
1   5WS  4/2/2023    A
3   DC6  5/3/2023    C
3   DC6  6/1/2023    C
```

I am trying to get:

```
ID   CPT        SVCDate              Vendor
1    A3A,5WS    1/14/2023,4/2/2023   A,A
2    DC6        1/23/2023            B
3    DC6,DC6    5/3/2023,6/1/2023    C,C
```

My version of SQL doesn't support STRING_AGG()

Thanks a lot :)

```
SELECT ID,
       CPT,
       SVCDate,
       Vendor,
       STUFF((SELECT ', '+CPT
              FROM Claims CD
              WHERE CD.ID = D1.ID
          FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2, ''),
       STUFF((SELECT ', '+ CAST(SVCDate AS VARCHAR)
         FROM Claims CD1
         WHERE CD1.ID = D1.ID
         FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,''),
       STUFF((SELECT ', '+Vendor
         FROM Claims CD2
         WHERE CD2.ID = D1.ID
         FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')
        
FROM Claims D1
GROUP BY ID,
       CPT,
       SVCDate,
       Vendor
```

The above code is not working. I am expecting this result:

```
ID   CPT        SVCDate              Vendor
1    A3A,5WS    1/14/2023,4/2/2023   A,A
2    DC6        1/23/2023            B
3    DC6,DC6    5/3/2023,6/1/2023    C,C
```

Comment: [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql) & [String\_agg for SQL Server before 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017). Though, personally, I'd suggest you rethink this requirement.

Comment: This isn't grouping by `STUFF`, this isn't  even the important part. This is an old trick to aggregate strings using *XML*. `STUFF` is there only to remove the extra comma. All supported SQL Server versions have STRING_AGG so this trick is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this without querying the table once for each column. You can just build an XML or JSON object of all the rows, and break them back out again using `.nodes` or `OPENJSON`.

Then re-aggregate it using `FOR XML PATH('')`.

```
SELECT
  c.ID,

  STUFF((
      SELECT ', ' + x2.r.value('(CPT/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
      FROM x1.xmlData.nodes('r') x2(r)
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS CPT,

  STUFF((
      SELECT ', ' + x2.r.value('(SVCDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
      FROM x1.xmlData.nodes('r') x2(r)
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS SVCDate,

  STUFF((
      SELECT ', ' + x2.r.value('(Vendor/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
      FROM x1.xmlData.nodes('r') x2(r)
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Vendor

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.ID
    FROM Claims c
) c1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CPT, SVCDate, Vendor
    FROM Claims CD2
    WHERE CD2.ID = D1.ID
    FOR XML PATH('r')
) x1(xmlData);
```

Or with JSON

```
SELECT
  c.ID,

  STUFF((
      SELECT ', ' + x2.CPT
      FROM OPENJSON(x1.json)
        WITH ( CPT varchar(max) ) x2
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS CPT,

  STUFF((
      SELECT ', ' + x2.SVCDate
      FROM OPENJSON(x1.json)
        WITH ( SVCDate varchar(max) ) x2
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS SVCDate,

  STUFF((
      SELECT ', ' + x2.Vendor
      FROM OPENJSON(x1.json)
        WITH ( Vendor varchar(max) ) x2
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Vendor

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.ID
    FROM Claims c
) c1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CPT, SVCDate, Vendor
    FROM Claims CD2
    WHERE CD2.ID = D1.ID
    FOR JSON PATH
) x1(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have extra columns in SELECT and GROUP BY that you don't need

```
SELECT ID,
       STUFF((SELECT ', '+CPT
              FROM Claims CD
              WHERE CD.ID = D1.ID
          FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2, '') AS CPT,
       STUFF((SELECT ', '+ CAST(SVCDate AS VARCHAR)
         FROM Claims CD1
         WHERE CD1.ID = D1.ID
         FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS SVCDate ,
       STUFF((SELECT ', '+Vendor
         FROM Claims CD2
         WHERE CD2.ID = D1.ID
         FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS Vendor
        
FROM Claims D1
GROUP BY ID
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/236021/3)

Comment: @ND_OG_89, mark this as the answer to your question and upvote rather than just leave a comment.

Comment: I've marked the answer,. I can't upvote yet. I just joined

Comment: The subqueries should probably ensure that they qualifying *all* the columns, not just the ones in the `WHERE`. 'Tis a bad habit to not do so.

Comment: `FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')` would be wise, in case of XML escaping